# server side rendering not generating with Nextjs

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am new to nextjs, in my application uses ContextProvider along with App.js like below[image]

and layout also wrapped around the main Component but serverside rendering (HTML is not generating on the view source) like below

[image]

my observations are that I removed all the wrappers then SSR is happening can someone suggest how to handle correctly

Comment: share your code where your are doing ssr

Comment: Hi @illiachill 
here is the piece of code for SSR plz look into it
export async function getServerSideProps(props: any) {
  let defaultBrand = BRAND_NAME_EN;
  const locale = props?.locale;
  console.log(locale, 'locale')
  if (locale === "fr") defaultBrand = BRAND_NAME_FR;
  const headFooterRes: any = await getHeaderAndFooterDetailsWithDefaultLocale(
    defaultBrand,
    locale
  );  
  const headerFooterData = (await headFooterRes?.data) || null;
  return {
    props: {
      headerFooterData,      
    },
  };
}